# Determine machine's logon domain from command line

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, command-line-interface

Trying to figure out if there is an environment variable or another method to get a given machine's logon domain from simple command line script.

The variable `%USERDOMAIN%` will provide me with the domain my user is - and in a domain trsut scenario does not return the machine's domain, rather MY domain.

The idea is that I want to be able to have my cmd script code not care about what domain it is in, but sitll be able to determine that info at runtime.

There's VBScript method here:

```
Set objRootDSE = GetObject("LDAP://RootDSE")
strDomain = objRootDSE.Get("DefaultNamingContext")
WScript.Echo strDomain
```

Another method is this:

```
net config workstation | findstr /C:"Workstation domain"
```

which outputs:

```
Workstation domain                   DOMAINNAME
```

But since there is no command line equivalent to unix `cut`, I am finding it difficult to get this info into a variable.

Comment: I'd also be happy with the non-NetBIOS name - i.e. `domainname.mydomain.net`

Comment: ^ That's also called the FQDN, or Fully Qualified Domain Name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it for you:

```
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims= " %%d in ('net config workstation ^| findstr /c:"Workstation domain"') do set machinedomain=%%f
```

Then `%machinedomain%` will contain the domain.  Note that "Workstation domain" is case-sensitive there.

Comment: +1 - Works for me. I'd do a "tokens=3", and I'm more of a "FIND" guy, but that's all I'd change: for /f "usebackq tokens=3" %%i in (`net config workstation ^| find "Workstation d
omain"`) do echo Domain is %%i

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm.
Added an @ to get rid of a echoed command:
`...do @set MACHINEDOMAIN=%%f`

Comment: Hilarious thing about windows is that this won't work for a version in another language.

Answer (score 1):

Wmi:

```
wmic path win32_computersystem get domain
```

Answer (score 0):

Powershell:

```
get-wmiobject win32_ntdomain
```